# how can the stack be displayed after a possibly blocking event?

Tags: java, multithreading, android-studio

We are developing a multi-threaded Android app with Android Studio, and we are strongly suspecting that the main GUI thread blocks occasionally. The issue is easily reproduced.
Unfortunately, since we do not know exactly where the thread blocks, we don't have any good candidates for breakpoints
Is there a way, as soon as the thread seems blocked, to halt it and inspect its stack to see which method is at fault?

Comment: Doesn't Android Studio's debugger have any Pause button? In desktop version, once you hit Pause, you can inspect stack trace of any thread

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add a [mcve] please?